# What is alternative to performing a left join on GTE or LTE conditions?

Tags: join, hive, left-join, hiveql, non-equi-join

I am required to use a specific old version of HIVE that prevents me from joining 2 tables on GTE or LTE conditions. For example what is the equivalent of

```
select *
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
  and (t1.date >= t2.date and t1.date <= t2.date+7) -- i can no longer do this condition
```

What is an alternative query to this?

Comment: Have you tried BETWEEN? And which version of Hive are you using?

Comment: @Ramesh between will not work as well

Comment: @Ramesh between will also not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative is to move GTE/LTE part of condition to the `where` clause which will be applied after join as a filter:

```
select *
  from table1 as t1
       left join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 where (t1.date >= t2.date and t1.date <= date_add(t2.date,7)) 
       or t2.id is null
```

Comment: You need to add an `OR table2.id is null` to your where clause.  Otherwise you end up with an inner join.

Comment: @ Andrew. Thanks, forgot about it. fixed